# Как передать изображение в виде base64 на сервер из URL java

Tags: java, post, изображения, base64

Не могу прийти к решению
Нужно передавать на сервер картинку в формате base64, но из URL.
Тоесть получаю url с сылкой на изображение и отдаю на сервер post методом уже **изображение** в формате base 64.

Answer (score 1):

Для HTML5 это делается примерно так ([оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/5506820))

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // создаётся пустой тэг
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // копирование из <image>
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    //берём данные в формате png
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    //добавляем заголовок (не обязятаельно)
     var content= dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    return content;
}
```

Если нет гарантированной поддержки HTML5 на стороне браузера, то надо на сервер грузить ссылку и уже на нём проводить скачивание контента.